# Apply a 2d color histogram on images

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to obtain the 2D histogram values of some images, but I'm really lost with it. If I'm not wrong I can do this with `np.histogram2d()` from `numpy`.

What I'm trying is

```
def hist2d(img, bins):
     b_channel, g_channel, r_channel    = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
     channels = [b_channel, g_channel, r_channel]

     c1 = np.histogram2d(b_channel,g_channel, bins=bins_per_hist)
     c2 = np.histogram2d(g_channel,r_channel, bins=bins_per_hist)
     c3 = np.histogram2d(r_channel,b_channel, bins=bins_per_hist)

     # Finally concatenate results
     # np.concatenate()

    return result
```

My idea is,

- Split the image in 3 channels.
- Obtain the 3 histograms 2d.
- Return a numpy array of the concatenation of 3 normalized 2D histograms: B/G, B/R and G/R.

You think is correct the idea? How I have to use the `np.histogram2d()`function? I don't understand how I have to pass the bins values. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html), says a list of 2 values, but what values? Ijust have one.

*Note:* I'm doing it with `numpy` but maybe another option colud be `openCV`.

Thank you very much! I'm sure its easy but I want to learn too!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier in Python/OpenCV.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2

# read image
img = cv2.imread('mandril3.jpg')

# calculate 2D histograms for pairs of channels: BG, GR, RB
histBG = cv2.calcHist([img], [0, 1], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])
histGR = cv2.calcHist([img], [1, 2], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])
histRB = cv2.calcHist([img], [2, 0], None, [256, 256], [0, 256, 0, 256])

# merge 3 single channel historgrams into one color histogram
hist = cv2.merge([histBG,histGR,histRB])

# view results
cv2.imshow("hist", hist)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# save result
# result is float and counts need to be scale to range 0 to 255
hist_scaled = cv2.normalize(hist, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
cv2.imwrite('mandril3_histogram.png', hist_scaled)
```

Color Histogram:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! But I have one question, what is the parameter that defines the number of bins? That's why I chose numpy, because I don't know what is the bins param with this function. Thank you very much again!!!

Comment: The [256,256] argument is the number of bins. But why could you not just search OpenCV or Google for documentation on it. See https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d0d/tutorial_py_2d_histogram.html